# Debian - Postfix + Dovecot, send but not receive mail

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot

I have followed the instructions in this [tutorial](http://sharkysoft.com/wiki/how_to_build_a_virtual_user_email_server). I can successfully sent emails but i cannot receive. Here is exactly what happens:

When i sent an email from my hotmail account if i do

```
# ls /home/vmail/example.com/info/mail/new/
1386353921.V918aI67830c7M607456.myvps
```

i see the mail, but if i login to squirrelmail i don't.

here is my /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = myvps
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = myvps, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
virtual_minimum_uid = 999
virtual_uid_maps = static:999
virtual_gid_maps = static:999
```

Here is the dig output:

```
# dig example.com MX +short
0 mail.example.com.
```

**EDIT**
And here is my /var/log/mail.log when i send an email to my vps email account:

```
Dec  6 13:46:01 myvps postfix/smtpd[23920]: connect from dub0-omc3-s2.dub0.hotmail.com[157.55.2.11]
Dec  6 13:46:01 myvps postfix/smtpd[23920]: F0DB267E137F: client=dub0-omc3-s2.dub0.hotmail.com[157.55.2.11]
Dec  6 13:46:02 myvps postfix/cleanup[23925]: F0DB267E137F: message-id=<DUB118-W1118B8BBE2A4DE54F2886CF8D60@phx.gbl>
Dec  6 13:46:02 myvps postfix/qmgr[23905]: F0DB267E137F: from=<myaccount@hotmail.com>, size=1650, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  6 13:46:02 myvps postfix/smtpd[23920]: disconnect from dub0-omc3-s2.dub0.hotmail.com[157.55.2.11]
Dec  6 13:46:02 myvps postfix/virtual[23926]: F0DB267E137F: to=<info@example.com>, relay=virtual, delay=0.08, delays=0.06/0.02/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Dec  6 13:46:02 myvps postfix/qmgr[23905]: F0DB267E137F: removed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with with mailbox_command. 
When i just commented out the line containing mailbox_command, it worked.

So if anyone faces the same problem simply run:

```
sed -i "/mailbox_command/ s/^/# /" /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Answer (score 0):

At this line in `main.cf`

```
mydestination = myvps, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
```

Add `domain.com`

```
mydestination = myvps, localhost.localdomain, domain.com, localhost
```

Comment: Still nothing...

Comment: What does `/var/log/mail.log` say when you send a mail to the server? Post in your question. Is the client you are sending from resolving `domain.com` correctly? If you don't own the domain `domain.com`, you should use another domain which you control instead.

Comment: i edited my post.

Comment: Can you find the mails you send in /home/info/Maildir ?